# Modify an object using Reflection in c#

Tags: c#, object, reflection, propertyinfo

I'm creating a function will read all properites from an object check from certain value and modify it, I want to return back a final object with the modified result.

```
 public object SystemSettings 
    { 
        set 
        {
            propertyGridEditor.SelectedObject = GetFullPropertyPaths(value); 
        } 
    }

 private static object GetFullPropertyPaths(object finalResult)
    {
        foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in finalResult.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if (propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(string))
            {
               object propertyValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(finalResult);
               if (propertyValue.ToString().StartsWith("\\"))
                {
                    string result = Sys.Config.ConfigurationRootFolder + propertyValue.ToString();
                    propertyInfo.SetValue(finalResult, result);
                }
            }
        }
        return finalResult;
    }
```

I know I migh need to use some sort of Deep copy of an object, I want to make sure I'm on the right track or if I missing something. 
Thanks

Comment: Do you want to change the values of the object passed by parameter, or to create a copy of finalResult, operate over it and return this copy?

Comment: the object I'm passing contains multiple properties, I want change their values return back an object either the same object or copy of it.

Comment: So what is your question? Do you have problems with the code that you have posted?

Comment: Have you considered writing a wrapper for your object - this will avoid having to do (relatively expensive and cumbersome) reflection? It might not be suitable for your scenario (either because you can't inherit appropriately [e.g. class is sealed], or because you need to modify the actual values of the object or something like that), but it's often a much neater solution if you can do it.

Comment: @Martin My problem is the properties value are not set right for this object  the class this object I try to modify seald class, I think I need to create a deep copy of the object and return it, this method is called from a property to set a propertyGrid so I want to grab the object before set to the perperty grid and change some properties and send it back to the property grid

Comment: Sounds like [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/299295). Why do you need to change that property? `PropertyGrid` object can be facade (`PropertyDescriptor` + `ICustomTypeDescriptor`) so that you do not edit raw properties of object, but something (via `TypeConverter`s and `UITypeEditor`s). Or you may just do a deep copy by making object serializable and serialize it/deserialize copy, then use copy to edit and to discard/assign original object reference.

Comment: @J-P: You problem statement is somewhat vague. You show some code that at least from my casual inspection seems alright and then you explain that is does not work without giving any details. How does it not work? Show us the expected versus the actual outcome.